# CURL in PHP to extract text?

Tags: php, dom, curl

I have a URL that I would like to CURL in PHP and extract select data from as PHP variables (and print the variables for now).

The output of the URL if I view in a browser looks like the following:

```
{"offset":0,"results":[{"price/_currency":"USD","title":["titlewords","titlewords"],"price":1.99,"status":"In Stock","price/_source":"$1.99"}]
```

What is the best approach to do this? Should I use domxpath or is there a more efficient way?

Thank you

Comment: `json_decode()`, by the way that string missed a `}` closing

Comment: Thank you - I checked out the documentation for json_decode but I am a little confused on how it can set variables to those values in what is being returned?

Comment: just use the one that `curl` returned and put it inside

Comment: [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) will get you the variables without you having to define them yourself. There aren't very many though - just do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you are already successfully sending your POST Request to the URL and you are getting that string returned, and now you're asking how to decode the data.

Well first of all. That string is [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/). It's a way to storing and exchanging data between applications.

In PHP there is a function to decode this into an array. The function is called [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and it does exactly what the name says, it decodes json into a variable/array to be used in PHP.

Comment: Thank you - can you help me with an example of how to format the json_decode() statement?

Comment: I linked you to the function documentation.

You just use it $var = json_decode($json_string);